# Hide table border at page break in PDF, using phantomjs

Tags: node.js, pdf, html-pdf

I have a pdf exported using html-pdf as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96N8Q.png)

I want the border of the last row of the table to be displayed as shown below. Currently, i use html-pdf.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8jrC.png)

i used the following css but the table row when exporting pdf is not as expected.

CSS:

```
   table {
     page-break-inside: avoid;
   }

   tr {
     page-break-inside: avoid;
   }

   td {
     page-break-inside: avoid;
   }
```